# How to remove substring from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have value of one variable is 03_ButtonAdd. I want to remove _ButtonAdd from it. means I want only numeric value. How to do it in javascript.?

Comment: [MDN String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) This is a very basic question, and it is very easy to find the answer. Show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'03_ButtonAdd'.replace('_ButtonAdd', '');
// returns: '03'
```

[**`String.prototype.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) documentation.

Assuming:

```
var s = '03_ButtonAdd';
```

Some more other methods would be:

```
s.substring(0,2);
parseInt(s, 10)   // returns `3`, not `'03'`
/\d+/.exec(s)[0]; // Regex -> get all digits.
```

And some more ugly / inefficient alternatives (Don't use these):

```
s.split('_')[0];  // Split at _, get first index of array.

var out = '';
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    if(isFinite(s[i])){
        out += s[i];
    }
}                // Seriously, now I'm just messing around, don't use this.
```

Comment: How in the world is a regular expression ugly and inefficient? Yikes

Comment: Wait, a second ago you thought `parseInt` would return `NaN`. Suddenly it gets added to your answer. Seriously dude, if you just learned something new from someone else, don't steal it from them.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I messed up my variable. That's why it returned NaN

Comment: @epascarello: Okay, Regexes as small as this are maintainable, but if you get used to using them too much, you'll end up using them for cases where they're not required, making your code harder to understand. There. Changed the wording.

Comment: Also, @epascarello, while the difference is impossible to notice, `parseInt` [seems to be twice as fast](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-parsefloat-vs-regex) as using a regex. I think a downvote is hardly warranted for that reason, especially since the first part exactly answers the OP's question to remove `'_ButtonAdd'` from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start and end point inside `substring()` function from where you want to collect the string. Like

```
var str = "03_ButtonAdd";
var result = str.substring(0, 2);
//rsult is 03
```

Answer (score -1):

Grabbing the number as a string

```
var str = "03_ButtonAdd";
var numStr = str.match(/(\d+)/)[0];  //"03"
```

if you actually want the number, you would use parseInt

```
var num = parseInt(str, 10);  //3
```

Comment: Why am I keep getting downvotes today? Love mystery downvotes on old questions, especially one where the selected answer copied my solution after saying it was wrong.